# can UIView get a reference to UIViewController automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Today I find a strange thing, it seems that my `UIView` can get a reference to my `UIViewController` automatically

My `UIView` declare a controller property:

```
@interface YLSFirstView : UIView
   @property YLSFirstViewController *controller;
@end
```

In the .m file, I set that controller as the button target:

```
[button addTarget:self.controller action:@selector(testAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Of course, in controller .m file, I implement that action(`testAction`)

Following is the code instance and init the `UIView` and `UIController`, however I never set the controller `@property`!

```
YLSFirstViewController *first = [[YLSFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
first.view = [[YLSFirstView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
```

What surprise me is: when I tap the button, the action "`testAction`" in `ViewController` get invoked...

I'm quite confuse by this, why the `@property` controller in the `UIView` get a correct reference? Are there some unspoken rules in `iOS`?

**PS:** by the way, there are several times (not quite often), the button lose respond, when I tap it, nothing happened. In most time, it just worked fine. I don't know if there's something related to what I described above.

Would you please tell me the answer? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the UIView get a reference to UIViewController automatically, it is the responder chain.

I find the paragraph in apple development library , reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

**For Action messages, When the user manipulates a control, such as a button or switch, and the target for the action method is nil, the message is sent through a chain of responders starting with the control view.**

The image below demonstrates responder chain path, you should know that if the initial object—either the hit-test view or the first responder doesn’t handle an event, UIKit passes the event to the next responder in the chain.

As you can see in the image, UIViewController is in the responder chain, so if the UIViewController's topmost view (It is YLSFirstView here) can't handle the event, it will be passed to it's UIViewController(It is  YLSFirstViewController here).

[image]

Comment: yes, i think it make sence, i know little about responder chain, now i get a clue, thanks a lot!